# ember/handlebars - How to toggle object class based on boolean?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cp-validations

I have a form styled with `bootstrap4` and am using `ember-cp-validations` to validate it.

```
  <div class="form-group {{if showNameError 'has-danger' ''}}">
    <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">{{fa-icon "user"}}</span>
        {{input id="name" class="form-control" value=user.firstname placeholder="Enter your Name" focus-out=(action (mut showNameError) true)}}
      </div>
    </div>

    {{#if showNameError}}
      {{#if (v-get user "firstname" "isInvalid")}}
        <div class="form-control-feedback container">
          <span>{{v-get user 'firstname' 'message'}}</span>
        </div>
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
```

Using `{{if showNameError 'has-danger' ''}}`, I am able to set the class to `has-danger` when `showNameError` is true, however when it is false, the class remains there and the `has-danger` persists.

1. When the page loads
   [image: step 1]
2. When I force the error
   [image: step 2]
3. After I fix the error
   [image]

As you can see, after I fix the error the `has-danger` class remains. My question is, can I make it so the class toggles based on whether the input is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to and it is performing as it should.

```
<div class="form-group {{if showNameError (if (v-get user 'firstname' 'isInvalid') 'has-danger' 'has-success')}}">
<label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
<div class="cols-sm-10">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">{{fa-icon "user"}}</span>
    {{input id="name" class="form-control" value=user.firstname placeholder="Enter your Name" focus-out=(action (mut showNameError) true)}}
  </div>
</div>

{{#if showNameError}}
  <div class="form-control-feedback container">
    <span>{{v-get user 'firstname' 'message'}}</span>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the {{if ... }} syntax. I thought this had to be {{#if ...}}. Is this an ember or ember-cp-validation construct?

Comment: I pulled it from the ember docs. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/conditionals/